# Issue while installing angular cli on stable node version

Tags: command-line, software-installation

i was trying to install angular cli and i had these two warning i'm afraid that will bother me later i don't know how to fix it help me please

maryam@maryam:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead

changed 227 packages, and audited 228 packages in 17s

26 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
maryam@maryam:~$ npm fund
maryam

maryam@maryam:~$

i tried to fix it using
npm install -g npm-check-updates
then ncu -u  --packageFile package.json
npm update
npm install
and finally sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
but the problem still there help please

Answer (score 0):

Try command 'ng v' and check if it ask any question about google and say N as no. If it shows angular versions then it means angular/cli is installed